# Value array selector as a variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I hope someone can help me. I been crashing down my head trying to end up with a solution for this, here is the deal, I have a function passing through some variables like this:

```
function createTaskView(results, listName, container, url, groupby) {
```

The variables are so simples, "results" it's an array, the other ones are simply strings. So far so good.

Then I start an $.each loop in the array like this:

```
function createTaskView(results, listName, container, url, groupby) {

    $.each(results, function (index, task) {
        var tr = '<tr>' +
                   '<td><a href="'+ url +'Lists/'+ listName +'/EditForm.aspx?ID='+ task.ID +' ">' + task.ID + '</a></td>' +
                   '<td>' + task.Year + '</td>' +
                   '<td>' + task.Site_x0020_Name + '</td>' +
                '</tr>';

        $(container + ' .' + task.groupby).append(tr);

    });

});
```

The problems starts here

```
$(container + ' .' + task.groupby).append(tr);
```

I know there is no key in my DB call "groupby", I meant to use the string value passed into the function in here:

```
function createTaskView(results, listName, container, url, groupby) {
```

So, if the variable groupby is like this:

```
var groupby = Year;
```

I want this:

```
task.groupby
```

To be equal like this:

```
task.Year
```

I don't know if I make myself clear.
Please someone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of `container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access a property whose name is stored in a variable so

```
$(container + ' .' + task[groupby]).append(tr);
```

Also make sure that the value of `container` is a proper selector like `#myid` for an id selector not just `myid`

Comment: jajajajaja that was exactly the answer to my problem, a beginner problem but yet it makes me suffer, jajaj I don´t know why I dind't thing in that.
Thank you so much @ArunPJohny